# Pointing a domain to a specific controller/action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, cname, domain-name

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4 application that I'm writing and one of its functions is to provide my customers with their own website. The default way the websites can be reached is `http://www.abc.com/cb/acme`

I would like to give them the ability to point their own domain to this location so the above becomes `http://www.acme.com`

Can I just have them point `acme.com` to `http://www.abc.com/cb/acme` using the cname? In your opinion and experience whats the best way of doing this?

**Update:** I also need it to be google and bing crawler friendly if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide each customer a new subdomain. If `http://www.abc.com` is your main website domain, then your customer `acme` can have a domain as

```
http://acme.abc.com
```

You can't give directly a new domain to every customer, this is the way out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can config in file Global.asax eg:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "CategoryDetails", // Route name
            "{cid}/{id}/{categoryName}/{articleName}.htm", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "News", action = "Detail", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional, articleName = UrlParameter.Optional, cid = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

code in view eg:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Detail", "News", new { cid = Model.CategoryId, id = obj.ID , categoryName=Model.TitleContent, articleName = "1" })%>">
```